# How to use private repo gem in Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker

I would like to load a private gem in my rails app (I'm using docker and rails 5).

So first I add the gem in my **gemfile** :

`gem 'my_gem', '0.1.4', git: "https://#{ENV['GITHUB_TOKEN']}@github.com/Orga/my_gem"`

Then when I try to `docker-compose build`, this is what I get :

> > fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address

So  I tried `docker-compose run web bundle install`. They ask me for my login. I've got no error, but the gemfile is updated as below :

```
GIT
  remote: https://@github.com/Orga/my_gem
  revision: 391ae38ff06dfd360eb42a09256f4a5463fba559
  specs:
    my_gem (0.1.4)
      rails (>= 5.0.0.beta3, < 5.1)
      roo (~> 2.1.0)

GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  ...
```

1. This line seems really weird to me : `remote: https://@github.com/Orga/my_gem` .
   So is it the good way to load a private gem ?
2. When I `bundle install` it asks for my login, so it will probably cause trouble in production right ?

## EDIT

When I put direclty the token into the gemfile everything works. 
So the env var is not called properly.

I tried :

**.env**

```
GITHUB_TOKEN=...
```

**gemfile**

```
gem 'my_gem', '0.1.4', git: "https://#{ENV['GITHUB_TOKEN']}@github.com/Orga/my_gem"
```

AND also tried

**secrets.yml**

```
development:
  github_token: ...
```

**gemfile**

```
gem 'my_gem', '0.1.4', git: "https://#{Rails.application.secrets.github_token}@github.com/Orga/my_gem"
```

Comment: `remote: https://@github.com/Orga/my_gem` --- It seems you didn't correctly set the `ENV['GITHUB_TOKEN']`. How are you setting it?

Comment: Yes I realize that the env var is not set properly. Because when I put directly the token in the gemfile, everything works properly. 
I set it that way : I have a `.env' file with `GITHUB_TOKEN=...` . 
I also tried to put my env var in secrets.yml and call it with `Rails.application.secrets.github_token` but it doesn't work either.
So how can I make this env var accessible from the gemfile ?

Answer (score 1):

The best and most secure way of doing this is using bundle configuration

In your Gemfile, you should have:

```
source 'https://gem.fury.io/youraccount/' do
  gem "your_service", "~> 1.0.0"
end
```

And then, if you need to authenticate, this can be achieved by running the following terminal command:

```
bundle config https://gem.fury.io/youraccount/ yourauthtoken
```

I hope this helps answer your question!

Ben

Comment: Note, the source I noted above is GemFury, but this will work for any type of private repo.

Comment: It doesn't woks neither :/

Comment: What error are you seeing? Can you please provide more details!